# Statamic nginx local installation

Tags: laravel, nginx, statamic

I found in the web good examples - how to install Statamic on the localhost with mamp pro / mamp. But when I press the Nginx button in mamp pro things are not so easy I guess.

I want to use Nginx in my production server. I also want to use it in dev environment.

So I change the sample.nginx.conf to nginx.conf and changed root /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Statamic/new-statamic-site.com/;

Things do load but the images are not there and the subpages are not accessible.

What do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: My tip: use Laragon or something similar.

Comment: sry - but mamp pro is about 70 bugs and statamic is also not cheap. It will be possible to get a few parameters to get nginx running without the use of again some new tool to learn.

Comment: I still recommend taking a look at it, because there is nothing to learn. It is free as well. And Apache, MySQL, Nginx, ... ships by default (as well as PHP).

Comment: Ok. I use mac -  I go now with valet.  Its nice ;). Ty for tipp.